# Winform Trackbar values

Tags: c#, winforms, trackbar

I'm trying to make a slider in a winform. However I need my slider to move between values other than whole numbers.

For example, I have set my trackbar to a scale of 0 - 2 but it only allows me to 0, 1 or 2 when I need to have it go 0.01, 0.02, 0.03, 0.04 etc.

Is this even possible with a trackbar?
If so, how is this possible? My google searches haven't turned up anything.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2114485/how-to-use-floats-with-trackbar

Comment: Set it to a scale of 0 - 200 instead, and then divide the value by 100?

Comment: @duDE - I was mostly teasing, sorry. =)

Comment: You could try this post. I have not tested it but seems to be a valid option. http://bytes.com/topic/net/answers/478438-trackbar-double-values